# Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'String' with TableView

Tags: swift

I honestly have know idea anymore how to fix this conversion issue.

This is my array:

```
var family = [
    ["Angelfish", "Butterflyfish", "Surgeonfish"],
    ["Manatees", "Dolphins", "Whales"],
    ["Rays", "Sharks"],
    ["Triggerfish", "Porcupinefish", "Pufferfish", "Boxfish", "Trumpetfish"],
    ["Sea Turtles"],
    ["Moray Eels"]
]
```

This is my action for the row selection:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let familyVC = FamilyVC()
    familyVC.customInit(familyIndex: indexPath.row, title: family[indexPath.row])
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(familyVC, animated: true)
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you flattened out that array to show all the fish, one on each row?  Or do you have it broken down into sections.

If it's in sections, then you would have "Angelfish", "Butterflyfish", "Surgeonfish" in your first section, "Manatees", "Dolphins", "Whales" in the second, and so on.  So you would find those in the array like this:

```
familyVC.customInit(familyIndex: indexPath.row, title: family[indexPath.section][indexPath.row])
```

If you just want to show all the fish, one per row, you could flatten out the array with

```
let allFish = family.flatMap { $0 }
```

then use the allFish array.